# azure Active Directory Log in

Tags: c#, .net, azure

I need a little help i have register a Application in Azure Active Directory now I want to log in a user with resource and client  credentials i do not want to add client Id how can i log in the user?
I am using the following code having Exception

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

How can I solve it any suggestions?

```
private AuthenticationContext authContext;
public  void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string userName = "USERNAME";
        string password = "PASSWORD";

        string url = "https://.com/authentication";
        ClientCredential obj = new ClientCredential(userName, password);

        AuthenticationResult result = null;
        result = authContext.AcquireToken(url, obj);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    { }
}
```

Comment: On which line you get this exception? Did you debug your code? Related: [What is a `NullReferenceException` and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @soner i am getting the exception on this line of code

"result = authContext.AcquireToken(url, obj);"

Comment: Have you debugged through your code?  I doubt `authContext` is initialized at that line unless you are initializing it somewhere else?

Comment: you haven't instantiated your authContext object ,,

Comment: does i have to initialized my authContext null............?

Comment: @SonerGönül i have solved the exception now i have an other exception like"AADSTS70001: Application with identifier ABC was not found in the directory "abc"
Trace ID: "abc"
Correlation ID: "abc"
Timestamp: 2015-04-09 10:05:55Z"

can u guide me what kind of exception is this and how can i solve it.....?

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are using the `AuthenticationContext authContext` variable, but I can't see if you are initializing it.

I think you should check it first